# Is there a way to rename multiple files in a one liner on terminal?

Tags: command-line

I understand how to rename multiple files using for loops and such but I was wondering if there was a way to rename just two files in using one mv command while keeping certain strings consistent?

For example if I have two files that I want to rename a portion only:

```
txt_ID12123_R1_001_jan.txt
txt_ID12123_R2_001_jan.txt
```

And all I want to do is rename 'txt' but keep other string components the same:

```
exam_R1_001.txt
exam_R2_001.txt
```

Is there a one liner where you can use regex expressions to keep certain variables consistent? The R1 and R2 strings are very important to keep. I tried variations of:

```
mv txt_1D12123_R[1,2]_001_jan.txt exam_R[1,2]_001.txt
```

But this obviously doesn't work. Essentially the whole filename is the same except for R1 and R2, so I wanted to keep those strings in tact and to rename it accordingly.I also tried {1,2} but curly bracket made no difference. Just wondering - I only have to do this every so often so writing a loop for two files seemed silly, and writing mv twice is no big deal but I figured there HAS to be some short cut to it.

Comment: Do you want to remove or preserve the `_jan` component?

Comment: That would be fine - preserving everything after the R1/R2 variable are nice extra details to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mmv command to rename files

```
mmv '*txt_1D12123*' '#1exam#2'
```

You want to replace the the first occurrence of abc with xyz in all files in the current directory Please note that in the above example, I have enclosed the patterns in single quotes.

Comment: Is this built-in? mmv doesn't seem to work for me. What package is it from?

Comment: no it was not built in you can install it using command sudo apt install mmv

Answer (score 0):

Install the [`rename`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/rename) package,

```bsh
sudo apt install rename
```

then it's straightforward (well, if you're comfortable with perl):

```bsh
rename 's/.*(_R[12]_\d+).*/exam${1}.txt/' txt*.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am not comfortable at all with perl (in fact, I struggle quite a bit with it) but I will give this a shot. I am surprised it's not a simple thing built in already in linux...it seems like a very minor thing to me.

Comment: Actually this looks mostly like simple regex commands with sed which I am okay with somewhat...if someone leads me the right way:) thank you!

Comment: It is not working. I am not getting any error messages or anything but the file names remain identical and no new files with 'exam' are produced either. I'll have to play around with this.

Comment: what does `rename --version` show?

Comment: I have rename version until-linux 2.23.2

Comment: That version has a different syntax than what I showed you. Read the man page for usage.

Answer (score 0):

To Rename files using regex you need `rename`tool.

**Install rename tool**

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Then run follwing command to rename all files having `.txt` extension with the pattern that you specified i.e exam_R1_R2.txt

```bsh
rename 's/(\S)*_R(\d{1})_(\d+)_(\w{3})\.txt/exam_R$2_$3\.txt/' *.txt
```

**This first argument inside single quotes is regex pattern that matches and substitutes with file name with matching groups having R1 and R2 and the second argument `*.txt` denotes files having `.txt` extension**

*Learn more about regex [here](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285) and you can try regex testing [here](https://regex101.com/)*